# Why is my $scope not updating in my View in Angular when using $location with angular-route?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, mean-stack, partials

Does anyone know why my `$scope.userData` isn't rendering in my View when using `angular-route` and Angular's `$location` service together?

## My Situation:

In the code example below, I have an index page which iterates through users, `allUsers`, using angular's `ng-repeat`, as follows: `ng-repeat="user in allUsers` [note, for simplicity, I have left out the function in my controller snippet below that delivers `allUsers`, but is working correctly].

For each `user`, there is an edit button, which should run the `$scope.findOne` function, passing in the user itself as a parameter.

In my $scope.findOne function, a new partial is loaded using the `$location` service, and `$scope.userData` is updated to reflect this `user`. I want to access `$scope.userData` now on the new partial (my problem).

### Problem:

The new partial loads, the `user` object seems to pass along fine, however `$scope.userData` becomes inaccessible on the front-end.

#### PseudoCode (What I'd Like):

```
// Iterate through allUsers (`user in allUsers`)
// When Edit button is clicked for `user`:
    // Fire off `findOne` function passing in `user`
    // Set `$scope.userData` to `user`
    // Load `html/edit.html` partial
    // Show `$scope.userData` on the page (should be `user` info):
```

#### PseudoCode (What's Happening Instead):

```
// Iterates through allUsers (`user in allUsers`)
// When Edit button is clicked:
    // Fires off `findOne` function and passes `user`
    // Sets $scope.userData` (console logging it after shows changes)
    // Loads `html/edit.html`
    // **DOES NOT show `$scope.userData` and appears empty.**
```

#### Angular Module Setup:

Both the `/index.html` page and the `/edit.html` page appear to be setup correctly with the appropriate controller assignments:

```
// Define Module:
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

// Define Routes:
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'html/index.html', // root route partial
            controller: 'userController',
        })
        .when('/edit/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'html/edit.html', // edit page partial
            controller: 'userController',
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/',
        })
});
```

#### Angular Controller:

My angular controller (`allUsers` function now shown) shows the `findOne` function I'm trying to access, along with the use of the `$location` service:

```
app.controller('userController', ['$scope', 'userFactory', '$location', function($scope, userFactory, $location) {

    $scope.findOne = function(myUser) {
        $scope.userData = myUser;
        console.log($scope.userData); // shows changes...(?)
        $location.url('/edit/' + myUser._id); // redirects and partial loads OK...
    };

}]);
```

In the following Index HTML example, clicking the Edit button triggers the `$scope.findOne` function fine, redirects the page and updates `$scope.userData` (console logs OK), but on the partial itself, `$scope.userData` does not seem to reflect the changes (what gives?):

#### Index Page HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in allUsers">
    <h1>{{user.username}}</h1>
    <button ng-click="findOne(user)">Edit</button> <!-- runs findOne -->
</div>
```

#### Edit Partial HTML:

```
<h2>Edit:</h2>
{{userData}}  <!-- $scope.userData displays nothing? -->
```

## Summary:

Why does `{{userData}}` in my `Edit Partial HTML` not show anything?

I found a solution to my needs by creating a new controller, and having this other controller take over when the `/edit.html` page is loaded. The controller queries the DB on page load for the user based on `req.params.id`. This worked and I was able to carry on, but I have two separate controllers, when instead, I'd like to manage all CRUD operations from a single controller for my `Users`...(is this bad practice?)

I had initially tried the solution above, but got stuck with the $scope issue as outlined here in this write up. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong in getting my above data to render in my View? Your time and patience reading is genuinely valued! Thank you Stack Community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess (mostly b/c I use angular-ui-router) is that when you navigate to the edit partial, a new controller is being instantiated, so the data on the `$scope` is lost.

Here are two common approaches I've seen:

- Do what you described above to query the server for the user data using route params. Consider enabling the caching option for `$http` so it doesn't have to hit the server each time... but then you need to invalidate the cache when the data changes
- Create a service that queries the server for the list of users. This service makes the user list available to the controller, and returns an individual user for editing.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read! It is an odd issue: when I setup my Angular module, I did set the `/edit.html` partial to use the same controller as the index page: `.when('/edit/:id', { templateUrl: 'html/edit.html', controller: 'userController' })`. When I *do* create a new controller, my `$scope` works appropriately, but I'm confused why my first strategy doesn't seem to work? I'm still learning and new to MEAN, so I will have to lookup the `$http` caching you have described and the creation of custom services! Thank you for the possible solutions!

Comment: The first strategy doesn't work because in memory the Angular router is literally throwing away the first controller, and then making a new one when you navigate to the edit view. It's the same controller code, but the first one that had the data is gone. One way to see this happening is to insert a `console.log()` statement immediately above the line that declares the `$scope.findOne()` function. That log statement should happen when the controller is being instantiated, I expect you'll see 2 of them :)

Comment: Can you add that snippet from your last comment into your explanation and I can mark this one as answered by you? I really appreciate you helping me to understand how the $scope is affected by `angular-route` and how controllers are built when rendering partials. I didn't understand this and it makes a lot more sense now why my strategy wasn't working. I understand now when creating a new partial, that a new controller is necessary :) Thank you Sunil - your explanation helped tremendously!

Comment: Nvm, I see you had stated your explanation and I was just not properly understanding. Answer accepted, thank you!